# React table - removing white space in a column

Tags: reactjs, react-table

How can I get rid of this white space in my last column? I want the 3 dots to be closer to the end of the column.

I am using React table to build my table

[image]

```
  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: '',
        accessor: 'checked',
        Cell: () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />
            </div>
          );
        },
      },
      {
        Header: 'User ID',
        accessor: 'id',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name'
      },
      {
        Header: 'Email',
        accessor: 'email',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Mobile Number',
        accessor: 'mobileNumber',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Status',
        accessor: 'status',
      },
      {
        Header: '',
        accessor: 'action',
        Cell: () => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Button className="text-black" title="Edit User Schedule" onClick={handleClick}>
                <MoreVertIcon />
              </Button>
            </div>
          );
        },
      },
    ],
    [],
  );
```

The button is in the last column and I ned it to be smaller then the others.

Comment: Would you please share the specific snippet of your code please?

Comment: Are you using some kind of styling pack, or custom styling? This is probably a CSS question, not a React question.

Comment: @Halcyon i am using tailwind to do styling

Comment: I haven't used tailwind, but I'm sure there are ways you can customize the styling. Consider tagging this question as tailwind instead.

Comment: @Halcyon Thanks for the idea of using tailwind. That solved my problem